# making a sort algorithm but it works only sometimes

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

trying to make a basic sorting algorithm that slowly puts one number from list1 to list2. it should be lowest to highest. i do know there are better sorting algorithm but i want to make my own shitty own

```
list1 = [3,1,2,8,4,73,6,9,14,12,6712,23,76,111,312,42]
list2 = [-1]
w = 0

for i in range(len(list1)):
    while w != len(list1):
        
        if list1[w] > list2[w]:
            list2.append(list1[w])
            print(list2)
            w+=1
        elif list1[w] < list2[w]:
            if list1[w] < list2[w-1]:
                list2.insert(w-1,list1[w])
                print(list2)
                w+=1 
            list2.insert(w,list1[w])
            print(list2)          
            w+=1
    break
print(list2)
```

output:

```
[-1, 3]
[-1, 1, 3]
[-1, 1, 2, 3]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 8]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 73]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 73]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 73]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 14, 73]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14, 73]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14, 6712, 73]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14, 23, 6712, 73]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14, 23, 6712, 76, 73]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14, 23, 6712, 76, 73, 111]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14, 23, 6712, 76, 73, 111, 312]
[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 14, 23, 6712, 76, 73, 42, 111, 312]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/alexi/Downloads/test.py", line 17, in <module>
    list2.insert(w,list1[w])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

it all works fine until 6712 is introducted the it starts breaking.
not sure about the error aswell but it probally has to do with a number being in list2 at the very start. it doesnt work if there isnt a number in list2 at the very start so i put in -1 as a starting number. would like to make list2 completely empty at the start but not sure how to do that.
only thing i could think of to fix the sorting is making a def but have no idea where to start with that.
any help with the error/sorting/making list2 empty at the start? any help is great :)

Answer (score 1):

> not sure about the error aswell but it probally has to do with a
> number being in list2 at the very start

The first item in `list2` is not your problem. The issue is that you are at times making two insertions to your list (check code block under condition `elif list1[w] < list2[w]:`), but evaluating the loop condition only once in the beginning, thus the indexing error occurring.

> not sure about the error as well but it probably has to do with a
> number being in list2 at the very start

If `list2` is empty you are not able to evaluate your conditions like `list1[w] > list2[w]`, because there is no index 0 in an empty list. The solution is to insert the first element from your `list1` to `list2` outside your loop.

To me, it seems you are trying to implement something similar to the insertion sort algorithm, so checking that out might help you further. For example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/insertion-sort/ The success rate of your current solution is related to how sorted the list is to begin with. This is why it "works only sometimes".